# I have a working POST Request in SOAPUI an want to implement the same with Java Resttemplate

Tags: java, xml, rest, soapui

I have the following POST  Request in SOAPUI which seams to work

[image]

so i have  an endpoint a resource  A Header and a Header Parameter

when i want to implement this with  the RestTemplate i dont know how to add the header parameter  what i tried is

```
    public void setForward(String sessionId,String dn, String cf) {
    try {
        final String setForwardURL = "https://"+  getHost() + ":"+  getPort() +  "/inyama/service/logicaldevice/setForwarding";
        RestTemplate restTemplateSetForward =  new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("ClientSessionId",sessionId);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplateSetForward.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        String requestBodyCallForward =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
            "<ns3:SetForwarding xmlns:ns14=\"http://calllog.common.avaya.com/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns15=\"http://recording.common.avaya.com/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns9=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns5=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing\"" +
            "xmlns:ns12=\"http://conferencing.avaya.com/\" xmlns:ns6=\"http://com.avaya.inkaba.dal\"" +
            "xmlns:ns13=\"http://voicemail.common.avaya.com/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns7=\"http://com.avaya.inkaba.wstransfer\"" +
            "xmlns:ns10=\"http://ccragent.common.avaya.com/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns8=\"http://com.avaya.common.csta.extended\"" +
            "xmlns:ns11=\"http://conferencing.common.avaya.com/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns2=\"http://openapi.common.avaya.com/\"" +
            "xmlns:ns4=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer\"" +
            "xmlns:ns3=\"http://www.ecma-international.org/standards/ecma-323/csta/ed4\">" +
            "<ns3:device" +
            "typeOfNumber=\"dialingNumber\">" + dn + "</ns3:device>" +
            "<ns3:forwardingType>forwardImmediate</ns3:forwardingType>" +
            "<ns3:activateForward>true</ns3:activateForward>" +
            "<ns3:forwardDN typeOfNumber=\"dialingNumber\">"+ cf + "</ns3:forwardDN>" +
            "</ns3:SetForwarding>";
        HttpEntity<String> restRequest = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBodyCallForward, headers);
        final ResponseEntity<String> responseSetForward = restTemplateSetForward.postForEntity(setForwardURL, restRequest, String.class);
        HttpStatus statusCallForward =  responseSetForward.getStatusCode();
        boolean success = statusCallForward.is2xxSuccessful();
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        reporter.problemStackTrace(getClass(), e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        reporter.problemStackTrace(getClass(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I tried to set the header parameter with add but this does not work how can i add dies simple Header Parameter to my request

I get  a estClientException Bad Request  ehn i do no add my clienSessiinid i get a unauthorized access  Bot th login which is almost the same works but the login ha no parameter

```
    public String login() {
    String sessionId = "";
    try {
        final String loginURL = "https://"+  getHost() + ":"+  getPort() +  "/inyama/service/session";
        String requestBody =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<ns:userLoginRequest xmlns:ns=\"http://openapi.common.avaya.com/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
                "<userName>" +getUserName() + "</userName>"+
                "<userPassword>" + getUserPassword()+ "</userPassword>"+
                "<applicationName>talkbase</applicationName>"+
                "<loginSubscriptionRequest httpMethod=\"WEBSOCKET\" callBackUrl=\""+ callBackUrl() +" \">"+
                "<eventTypes>CapabilityExchangeServicesCallbackEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>MonitoringServicesCallbackEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>SnapshotServicesCallbackEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>CallControlFeaturesEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>CallAssociatedFeaturesEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>PhysicalDeviceFeaturesEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>LogicalDeviceFeaturesEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>DeviceMaintenanceEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>VoicemailServicesEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>RecordingServicesEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>CallLogEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>DirectoryEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>ImEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>PresenceEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "<eventTypes>LogoutEvents</eventTypes>"+
                "</loginSubscriptionRequest>"+
                "</ns:userLoginRequest>";
        RestTemplate restTemplateLogin =  new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplateLogin.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        HttpEntity<String> restRequest = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody, headers);
        final ResponseEntity<String> responseLogin = restTemplateLogin.postForEntity(loginURL, restRequest, String.class);
        HttpStatus status =  responseLogin.getStatusCode();
        boolean success = status.is2xxSuccessful();
        if ( success  ) {
            if ( responseLogin.hasBody() ) {
                String body = responseLogin.getBody();
                sessionId = getStringElement(body,"clientSessionID");
            }
        }
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        reporter.problemStackTrace(getClass(), e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        reporter.problemStackTrace(getClass(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return sessionId;
}
```

Comment: Looks right to me. What response are you getting that indicates the ClientSessionId is missing? Maybe it's wrong or some other issue.

Comment: i was an erre in tje header jnow it wworls